# How to resolve an xpath when xmlns is defined in the root element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

The following is a sample of the xml i'm trying to extract content from:

```
<CPM 
  xmlns:nc="http://STUFF1" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:jx="http://STUFF3" 
  xmlns:np="http://STUFF4" 
  xmlns:cj="http://STUFF5" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://STUFF6 STUFF7_STUFF8.xsd" 
  version="1.0" 
  key="KEYHERE" 
  xmlns="http://www.STUFF9.com">

  <Header>
    <Init>1234</Init>
    <Dest>MARS</Dest>
    <Control>12345xxx</Control>
  </Header>
  <Body>
  <PM>
    <nc:Msg>
        <np:EDSection>
          <np:EPO>
            <jx:ActivityDate>20180101</jx:ActivityDate>
```

I'm trying to extract variables using XPATH like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ns0="pri:vate"
    xmlns:nc="http://STUFF1"
    xmlns:np="http://STUFF4"
    xmlns:jx="http://STUFF3"
    xmlns:ea="http://OTHERSTUFF"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.STUFF9.com">

    <xsl:variable name="MYDATE" select="/CPM/Body[1]/PM[1]/nc:Msg[1]/np:EDSection[1]/np:EPO[1]/jx:ActivityDate[1]"/>
```

The problem is I have a java component that doesn't like `"xpath-default-namespace"` and I'd rather change the xslt than change the java component. Is there any other way to resolve an xpath from a source xml that defines xmlns with a url in the root element like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.STUFF9.com"` with `xmlns:s9="http://www.STUFF9.com"` and change the XPath expression to

```
/s9:CPM/s9:Body[1]/s9:PM[1]/nc:Msg[1]/np:EDSection[1]/np:EPO[1]/jx:ActivityDate[1]
```

After removing the default namespace, you have to define an explicit namespace. Here, I chose `s9` for this case, but any valid QName will do.